# Ansible: How do you link an ec2_asg to a ecs_cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, ansible, amazon-ecs

I'm attempting to automate the deployment of a project to an ecs_cluster in ansible.

I've created valid task definitions and services for said cluster, but I am am struggling to attach an ec2_asg to it. Thus not allowing the cluster to create and manage new tasks.

```yaml
    - hosts: localhost
      vars:
        aws_access_key: #key
        aws_secret_key: #key
        region: #region

      tasks:

      - name: Create task definition
        ecs_taskdefinition:
          aws_access_key: "{{aws_access_key}}"
          aws_secret_key: "{{aws_secret_key}}"
          region: "{{region}}"
          family: test
          launch_type: EC2
          network_mode: host
          containers:
          - name: test
            essential: true
            image: "nginx"
            portMappings:
            - containerPort: 80
              hostPort:      80
            cpu: 2048
            memory: 3884
          state: present

      - name: Create cluster
        ecs_cluster:
          name: test
          state: present
          aws_access_key: "{{aws_access_key}}"
          aws_secret_key: "{{aws_secret_key}}"
          region: "{{region}}"

      - name: Create service
        ecs_service:
          state: present
          name: test
          aws_access_key: "{{aws_access_key}}"
          aws_secret_key: "{{aws_secret_key}}"
          region: "{{region}}"
          cluster: test
          task_definition: test
          desired_count: 1
          deployment_configuration:
            minimum_healthy_percent: 75
            maximum_percent: 150
          #placement_constraints:
          #  - type: memberOf
          #    expression: 'attribute:flavor==test'
          #placement_strategy:
          #  - type: binpack
          #    field: memory



      - name: Create launch config
        ec2_lc:
          image_id: ami-0917237b4e71c5759
          instance_type: t3.medium
          name: test launch config
          aws_access_key: "{{aws_access_key}}"
          aws_secret_key: "{{aws_secret_key}}"
          region: "{{region}}"

      - name: Create scaling group
        ec2_asg:
          aws_access_key: "{{aws_access_key}}"
          aws_secret_key: "{{aws_secret_key}}"
          region: "{{region}}"
          launch_config_name: test launch config
          name: test scaling group
          state: present
          min_size: 1
          max_size: 1

      - name: Create scaling policy
        ec2_scaling_policy:
          aws_access_key: "{{aws_access_key}}"
          aws_secret_key: "{{aws_secret_key}}"
          region: "{{region}}"
          asg_name: test scaling group
          name: test
          state: present
          adjustment_type: "ChangeInCapacity"
          scaling_adjustment: -1
          min_adjustment_step: 1

      - name: Wait for register
        ecs_cluster:
          aws_access_key: "{{aws_access_key}}"
          aws_secret_key: "{{aws_secret_key}}"
          region: "{{region}}"
          name: test
          state: has_instances
          delay: 10
          repeat: 10
        register: task_output
```

Is there something obvious I'm missing in the playbook documentation? Or am I going to need to affect the instances created by the auto scaling group in some way, as to attach them to the cluster instead?